# Whenever the view of the google map is changed from map to satellite view and back, it looses poi.business labels

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to view the Google maps and often have to switch between Map and Satellite mode. But, whenever I switch to satellite mode, all the poi.business labels are gone. When I switch back to the Map mode, those labels are still not visible but the labels for roads and such are all visible.

How do I make sure that when the user comes back to Map mode, the poi.business labels are shown again?

[image: First time when the map is loaded, the labels are visible]

[image: Now moved to the satellite mode]

[image: Back to the Map mode, and the poi.business labels are missing]

Comment: What [version of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) are you using?  The experimental version is prone to breaking and weird problems.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I guess I am using Version 3 (release version), as per the explanation in the link given by @geocodezip. I am a business customer and am sending the client id.       "If you do not explicitly specify a version, you will receive the experimental version by default. Google Maps for Business customers who specify a client ID will receive the release version by default."